# Trying to Reduce WebApp's Bandwidth Consumption

Tags: php, mobile, cordova

For a PhoneGap webapp (Android + iOS) I would like to use some kind of mechanism to establish a persistent connection as I have to make very small but very frequent server (PHP) requests and the bandwidth consumed by the headers becomes an issue. I've read a lot about possible solutions but they are either too advanced for my level (amateur) or very unstable/experimental.

What is the easiest way to get rid of the headers' overhead? I'm also open to commercial solutions.

Comment: Did you try using socket-server in php?

Comment: Never heard of it! Let me have a look...

Comment: Sounds simple enough... although it seems Node.js is the bloggers' preferred solution? My PHP code is quite simple as it just performs MySql queries, so converting it to Node.js shouldn't be a problem. What do you think?

Comment: yep!! Nodejs is the right solution for you!!

Answer (score 0):

[NodeJs](http://nodejs.org) can be the best solution for your problem.

And [socket.io](http://socket.io) is the module you'll be wanting.

Comment: No explanation **why** it's the "best solution for the problem"? No explanation what functionality becomes available if Node and socket.io are used? No explanation about the protocol that isn't http which you're trying to suggest? Expand your question please, answers posting links are really not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Compression is the answer... try enabling gzip compression on Apache:

https://serverfault.com/questions/137823/how-to-enable-either-gzip-or-deflate-compression-via-htaccess

gzip is also widley used:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```